# Python graphics module

Tags: python

Hi im trying to create a python graphics window sized 100x100 pixels using john zelles simple graphics module import.

The item i need to recreate in the graphics window is below, I am just looking for tips on how to get started on this as i do not really know where to start (I could draw each thing individually but i need to use a loop) I have already tried it but I have become completely stuck, i know the circles need to have a radius of 5

[image]

thanks

UPDATE:
So with the help of @Alecg_O i have worked out this so far, however I cant work out how to duplicate the red circles numerous times, obviously I can copy and paste the code and change x & y coordinates but there must be a more efficient way?my code so far

`def circlePattern():
    win = GraphWin("Graphics", 100, 100)
    x = -15
    y = 20
    for i in range(3):
        x = x + 35
        for dx in range(-10,11,10):
            for dy in range(-10,11,10):
                drawCircle(win, Point(x+dx, y+dy), 5, "red")
    y = 20
    for i in range(2):
        y = y + 35
        for dx in range(-10,11,10):
            for dy in range(-10,11,10):
                drawCircle(win, Point(x+dx, y+dy), 5, "red")
    for x in range(10,86,35):
        for y in range(10,86,35):
            drawCircle(win, Point(x+dx, y+dy), 5, "white")`

Comment: Show us your code and point out where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Well, I guess an easy way would be to loop 81 times using integer division and modulus of both 9 and 3 to determine row, column and box and then draw the appropriate symbol based with the appropriate spacing. Does that help? Maybe you should post some code showing what you tried.

Comment: I thought i would go about the problem by just trying to create one of the 3x3 segments first, this is my code im trying to get it to alternate between the red and the white

Comment: `win = GraphWin("Graphics", 100,100)
    changeColour = {"red":"white", "white":"red"}
    colour = "red"
    for i in range(3):
        drawCircle(win, Point(10+(i*10),10), 5, "red")
    for i in range(3):
        drawCircle(win, Point(10+(i*10),20), 5, "red")
        while True:
            for i in (changeColour):
                color = "red"
                Circle.setFill(colour)
                colour = changeColour[colour] 
    for i in range(3):
        drawCircle(win, Point(10+(i*10),30), 5, "red")`

Comment: obviusly using `from graphics import *` @chipChocolate.py

Comment: @Dwool: Put your code in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the max benefit of loops, you will want to use a series of nested loops:

The distance from the left side of the window to the center of each set (the center of the white circle) is 10+5=15 pixels, so to evenly space your circles, the x and y coordinates should be:

```
(15,15), (50,15), (85,15)
(15,50), (50,50), (85,50)
(15,85), (50,85), (85,85)
```

Something like this will let you loop through the central point of each white circle:

```
for x in range(15,86,35):
    for y in range(15,86,35):
```

Next you need to loop through the points that make each circle in a set. For instance, for the first set these are:

```
(5,5),  (15,5),  (25,5)
(5,15), (15,15), (25,15)
(5,25), (15,25), (25,25)
```

But we want to make it general to whichever set is being drawn, we need to define these in terms of x and y:

```
(x-10, y-10), (x, y-10), (x+10, y-10)
(x-10, y),    (x,y),     (x+10, y)
(x-10, y+10), (x, Y+10), (x+10, y+10)
```

to get these in loop form, something like this ought to be sufficient:

```
for dx in range(-10,11,10):
    for dy in range(-10,11,10):
```

Finally you are ready to make your circles, and because the loop runs through all the needed points, you only need to define one circle! This will be at Point(x+dx, y+dy).

You may have noticed that right now this will simply draw all the circles in red. I'll leave it to you as a little challenge to make the middle ones white :) Hint: Don't worry about about if statements, just draw a white circle over top of the one drawn. You should only have to define one more circle if you place it in the right place in the loop.

Comment: I have got some of it working although i am still struggling on how to get the red one to be duplicated? @Alecg_O

Comment: `def circlePattern():
    win = GraphWin("Graphics", 100, 100)
    x = -15
    y = 20
    for i in range(3):
        x = x + 35
        for dx in range(-10,11,10):
            for dy in range(-10,11,10):
                drawCircle(win, Point(x+dx, y+dy), 5, "red")
    y = 20
    for i in range(2):
        y = y + 35
        for dx in range(-10,11,10):
            for dy in range(-10,11,10):
                drawCircle(win, Point(x+dx, y+dy), 5, "red")
    for x in range(10,86,35):
        for y in range(10,86,35):
            drawCircle(win, Point(x+dx, y+dy), 5, "white")`

Comment: Don't put code in comments, it's impossible to read.

Comment: You're on the right track exploring loops, but it's simpler than you've made it. The first loop loops through each x-center, the second loop loops through each y-center, the third loops through each dx needed, and the last loop loops through each dy needed. Just nest each loop directly under the one before it and then define your circle once under all four loops.

Comment: Ok @Alecg_O would you be so kind to explain to me how the three figured in dy and dx etc. actually work, I am a bit baffled by it. Im now trying to get it all in another loop to repeat 100 pixels to the right

Comment: the dx and dy loops each loop through from -10 to 10 by 10s, so -10, 0, 10. Therefore the first time through the loop, Point(x+dx, y+dy) = Point(15+(-10), 15+(-10)). The next time through dy's loop, it will be Point(15+(-10), 15+0), and so on. I don't really know how to explain it better than what's above.

Comment: Ok thanks @Alecg_O i am now trying to repeat the function to repeat it 100 pixels to the right, ive tryed naming all the points p1/p2 etc and re-assigning them at the end, e.g p1 = p1 + 100 but it doesnt work, any tips on how to repeat the function ?

Comment: Do you actually need to repeat the function? Otherwise by far the simplest way to continue the pattern is just lengthen the range - to continue 100 pixels to the right, just change "for x in range(15,85,35):" to "for x in range(15,185,35):".

Comment: Yes the function needs to be repeated unfortunately, i have tried to extend the range, any ideas how to go about this? @Alecg_O

Comment: If extending the range is not a valid option, you will need to encircle everything in another loop. As for what this one does, it may possibly work to have it change the coordinates of the window each time to just run the same program with the coordinates shifted using setCoords(). I'm not sure if that would work or not. Another option is to loop through moving the centers over each time. To do this, you will have to generalize the coordinates of each white circle center in terms of the central one, similar to how we did with the red circles around each central white one.